# not able to raise the alert when there are no items in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have got button click function written in jquery for checking that rows in grid in view  ... If there are no rows in kendo ui Grid it will raise the alert .... like given below

```
 <div class="leftSideDiv">
    <input id="btnExport" type="submit" name="Command" value="Export to Excel" />
</div>


  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    var grid = $('#costGridSelected').data("kendoGrid");
    var count = grid.dataSource.total();
    if (count <= 0) {   
         e.preventDefault();
        alert('No Selected Data To Export');           
    }       
  });
```

and i have got another textbox in a  view , when ever i have entered the value in that textbox and then press the enter button.. the above function is calling ..... and it is raising that alert (that I don't want to do)....

and i have tried another way to prevent this behaviour of form like the below

```
 $("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var grid = $('#costGridSelected').data("kendoGrid");
    var count = grid.dataSource.total();
    if (count <= 0) {          
        alert('No Selected Data To Export');
        return false;
    }       
});
```

in this case I am successful  for not raising an alert when the user entered value in text box and then press the enter button but if there are no items in grid I am not able to raise that alert that i need to raise...

would any pls suggest any idea and solution for this problem.
Many thanks in advance..

Comment: `count` what value this have currently, i suggest you to compare with `1` instead, because i think bydefault one row always gets in there.

Comment: Can you give us an example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var grid = $('#costGridSelected').data("kendoGrid");
    var count = grid.Rows.Count;
    if (count > 0) {
        return true;
      }
      else
     {          
        alert('No Selected Data To Export');
        return false;
    }       
});
```

try this....